# wordpress ajax form submition

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

> I need to send the mail in wordpress for the custom ajax form. The mail
>   should contain full name, email, phone number and the
>   message(comment). Please help me to do it.

I have included the html code as a shortcode in functions.php .

```js
function send_grivence(){
var form1 = jQuery("#myform").serialize();
console.log(form1);
jQuery.ajax({ 
         data: {action: 'send_form', form:form1},
         type: 'post',
         url: 'mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/',
         success: function(data) {
             console.log(data); //should print out the name since you sent it along
 
        }
    });
}
```

```html
         <form class="form-horizontal" id="myform">
            <fieldset>
             
               <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Username -->
                  <label class="control-label"  for="fullname">Fullname:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                     <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="your-name" class="input-xlarge">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Password-->
                  <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Id:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your-email" class="input-xlarge">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Password-->
                  <label class="control-label" for="number">Phone No:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                     <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" placeholder="your-phone no" class="input-xlarge">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Password-->
                  <label class="control-label" for="number">Comment:</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                     <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="your-message"></textarea>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="control-group">
                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="controls">
                     <a onclick="send_form()" class="btn btn-success">Submit</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </fieldset>
         </form>
```

Comment: And your actual _problem_ is …? Please go read [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

first jquery code to submit form via ajax

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery('#myform').submit(contactSubmit);
    function contactSubmit() {
        var contactForm = jQuery('#myform').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: contactForm,
            success: function (data) {
                // console.log(id);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

make sure that you place a action input in your form like this
`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm"/>`, just paste it before submit button. Note that `contactForm` function is called in function.php

then place a function in your function.php

```
function contactForm() {

    $name    = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email   = $_POST['email'];
    $phone   = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $message = $_POST['comment'];
    $quote   = 'Full Name: ' . $name . "\n\r" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\r" . 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\n\r" . 'Message: ' . $message . "\n\r";
    $to      = "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"; // put your email here
    $headers = 'From:' . $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n"; // put user's email here or duplicate your email
    $subject = 'Contact Form';

    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $quote, $headers ) === false ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        echo "<h3> Mail Sent Successfully Done</h3>";
    }
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_contactForm', 'contactForm' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contactForm', 'contactForm' );
```

Also make sure you replace your email in `"YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"`. also, make sure your `url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",` displays your full address. In local you might include `url: "/YOUR_FOLDER_HERE/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",` else in live server it works fine.

**EDIT**

```
<textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80" placeholder="your-message"></textarea>
```

change `name="name"` to `name="comment"`

Hope this helps.